# Is there a name for the partial order of metrics defined by induced topology subset.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, terminology

If we have two metrices on a space then these will induce a topology and since the subset relation defines a partial order on the power set then so does the relation $d_1 \succeq d_2$ if $\operatorname{Ind}(d_1) \supseteq \operatorname{Ind}(d_2)$ (where $\operatorname{Ind}(d)$ is the topology induced by $d$).

Has this relation $\succeq$ a name? (Note that $d_1\succeq d_2 \succeq d_1$ is the same as $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent)

Comment: See "Complete Lattice" in Wikipedia. This complete lattice also has the property of having unique lub's and unique glb's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the topology level it's just the standard refinement partial order on topologies (its standard complete lattice structure). So it's just the pulled back pre-order of this partial order via the "induce"-function, as it were. The pre-order comes from the fact that the metrisable topologies can have many different inducing metrics; I see no need for a name, I don't think it has been studied much. You could just call a metric finer, if it induces a finer topology, I suppose.

Comment: That the order is unnatural was not intentional. The main point in the question is about a partial order between metrics not that the order happened to be defined backwards. Should I take your answer to say that you'd call the relation between metrics the same? The relation in the topology case is called that a topology is finer or coarser - would that be a widely understood term if applied to metrics too?

Comment: I think it would be clear .